# The meaning of "rate filing"

Tags: canada, car-insurance

What does "[rate filing](https://edmontonjournal.com/news/politics/alberta-seeks-to-reward-good-drivers-with-auto-insurance-overhaul/wcm/d5b91c95-43b0-4066-8712-d4cae1a47a47/amp/)" mean in the following paragraph?

"The province is giving the AIRB new authority to tell insurers to return a portion of premiums to drivers if companies surpass profitability thresholds, as well as being able to request a rate filing from an insurer at any time, rather than just once a year."

The closest definition of "rate filing" I could find that relates to insurance is "file-and-use rating laws are regulations in the insurance industry that allow insurers to use new rates ahead of receiving approval from the state." However, I am not sure if this definition applies to the above paragraph. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Canadian Provinces have authority over Auto insurance similar to the way US states manage them.

The rate filing is the mechanism that the insurers use to specify key items in their rate algorithm. The government then can accept or reject that filing. It appears from your quote that they want the ability to set the rates more often, and limit the profits of the companies.